# PHP hacer una busqueda y extraer en otra variable

Tags: php, variables, text

Buenas estoy intentando hacer una cosa, me explico: De una variable tipo texto con varias lineas quiero extraer en otra variable la linea que contenga algo

lo he intentado de la siguiente forma:

```
$reporte strrpos(substr('$TextoGrande', -1, 0),'texto a buscar');
```

pero no me funciona, alguna sugerencia? Por cierto antes tengo esta linea, por si sirve:

```
$TextoGrande = trim($Todo);
```

vamos que lo que deseo es poner en la variable reporte todas las lines completas que coincidan con el texto a buscar

Gracias

Comment: Si quitas las comillas simples de textoGrande que pasa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, la más sencilla que se me ocurre es:

```
<?php
    $lineas = "línea 1 con algo de texto\n";
    $lineas .= "línea 2 con algo de texto\n";
    $lineas .= "línea 3 sin a_l_g_o de texto\n";
    $lineas .= "línea 4 sin a_l_g_o de texto\n";
    $lineas .= "línea 5 con algo de texto\n";

    echo "<ul>";
    $ret = explode("\n", $lineas);
    foreach($ret as $linea) {
        $pos = strpos($linea, "algo");
        if ($pos === false) {
            // No se encontró
        } else {
            echo "<li>" . $linea . "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Que mostrará el siguiente resultado:

```
línea 1 con algo de texto
línea 2 con algo de texto
línea 5 con algo de texto
```

Si en lugar de mostrarlo, quieres añadirlo en otro array, podrías eliminar los echo y en la parte else del if poner algo como:

```
$arr[] = $linea;
```

Habiendo declarado previamente el $arr como array.

Comment: muchísimas gracias track3r me ha servido de mucho!!

Un placer

Comment: Si te sirvió, considera aceptar la respuesta.

Comment: y si deseara eliminar de $TextoGrande la linea que contenga algo??

Comment: Entonces en el if del $pos === false, pones $TextoGrande .= $linea; y en el else no pones nada.

Comment: Te lo agradezco, pero no se tanto de catalán como para colaborar de alguna forma, de todas formas estaré al tanto.